# Create a Bitwise query in a array with c# MongoDB.Driver 2.0.1

Tags: c#, mongodb

*I use the latest C# MongoDB.Driver with version 2.0.1.*

*I have products in the collection like this:*

```
{
    "_id" : "55f7ceb2c01fcb2cd462e7a8",
    "Visible" : true,
    "Title" : "Product 1",
    "Description" : "",
    "ShowTimes" : [ 
        {
            "Day" : 1,
            "From" : 800,
            "To" : 1830
        }, 
        {
            "Day" : 2,
            "From" : 800,
            "To" : 1830
        }, 
        {
            "Day" : 4,
            "From" : 800,
            "To" : 1830
        }, 
        {
            "Day" : 8,
            "From" : 800,
            "To" : 2100
        }, 
        {
            "Day" : 16,
            "From" : 800,
            "To" : 1830
        }, 
        {
            "Day" : 32,
            "From" : 800,
            "To" : 1600
        }
    ],
    "Price" : 63.00,
    "Discount" : 20,
}
```

and i want to create a query with a bitwise compare like this:

```
{
    "Visible": true,
    "ShowTimes": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "$where": "this.Day & 8 == 8",
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do that from code?

Comment: In your example, only one document matches your criterion. And for that document, it is much easier to issue a normal query: `{ Day: 8 }`. In other words, in all other values of `Day`, applying `Day & 8` will produce `0`.

Comment: As stated, the example here may as well just directly look for the value of `8`. But your basic logic problem is that `$where` cannot be used within `$elemMatch`. Instead you need JavScript to traverse the array ( ie. `.some()` ) and do the comparison against each element. But in this case it would be better just to do the straight operator match for the value of `8`.

Comment: Maybe the document is not well done. In the list, it has elements with a Day of 13 (1 + 2 + 8)
With the old driver this was possible!

Comment: Not in the way you are coding it. You cannot mix the operators. It's either all JavaScript or nothing. You can compare other fields, but your whole array comparison needs to be in JavaScript.